# How can i add dotted line in front of menu

Tags: asp.net, css

I have following menu in asp.net:

```
<div id="left">
    <div id="menus" runat="server">
        <div id="left_menu">
            <div class="abc">
            </div>
            <div id="os">
            </div>
            <div class="btm">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="left_menu">
            <div class="cde">
            </div>
            <div id="l">
            </div>
            <div class="G">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to add dotted line in front of the menu so line should be as long the menu is. I searched online and on here cant find out how i will add the dotted line in front of the menu. I have css for dotted line here:

```
#horizontal_dotted_line
{
    border-top: 1px dotted #f00;
    color: black;
    background-color: #fff;   
    height: 1px;   
    width:50%;
}
```

But where should i put this div tag horizontal_dotted_line
so that it shows up in front of the menu?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say you're probably looking to use a class selector `.` instead of an ID selector `#`.

Comment: Have you get an example or image of what you're after? I don't understand the question at the moment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu is vertical, your line is horizontal, but you want your line to be as long as your menu?

Are you sure you don't want a vertical line? Just change the target ID of the CSS class from `horizontal_dotted_line` to `menus` and from a border top to a border left. (If this is a .NET control, have it target a class instead of an ID, because the .NET Id will be different)

```
#menus {
    border-left: 1px dotted #f00;
    color: black;
    background-color: #fff;   
    height: 1px;   
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: yes i want vertical dotted line in front of the menu. I did put the css under #menu tag but line is coming on top of the menu?

Comment: @NoviceMe, did you change `border-top` to `border-left` as I mentioned?

Comment: Yes i did. It is acting strangly. It is showing gap between two menus(left_menu 1 and 2). But no line in front of them?

Comment: @Brandon- I got it. It should have been border-right in my case. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="left">
    <div id="vertical-dotted-line">
        <div id="menus" runat="server">
```

With the css:

```
#vertical-dotted-line{
    border-left: 1px dotted #f00;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```